# Pandas groupby find common strings

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My Dataframe:

```
    Name              fav_fruit
0   justin              apple
1   bieber justin       apple
2   Kris Justin bieber  apple
3   Kim Lee             orange
4   lee kim             orange
5   mary barnet         orange
6   tom hawkins         pears
7   Sr Tom Hawkins      pears
8   Jose Hawkins        pears
9   Shanita             pineapple
10  Joe                 pineapple

df1=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['justin','bieber justin','Kris Justin bieber','Kim Lee','lee kim','mary barnet','tom hawkins','Sr Tom Hawkins','Jose Hawkins','Shanita','Joe'],
'fav_fruit':['apple'
,'apple'
,'apple'
,'orange'
,'orange'
,'orange'
,'pears'
,'pears','pears'
,'pineapple','pineapple']})
```

I want to count the number of common words in Name column after grouby on fav_fruit column, so for apple count is 2 justin bieber, for orange kim,lee and for pineapple is 0

Expected Output:

```
Name                  fav_fruit            count
0   justin              apple                2
1   bieber justin       apple                2
2   Kris Justin bieber  apple                2
3   Kim Lee             orange               2
4   lee kim             orange               2
5   mary barnet         orange               2
6   tom hawkins         pears                2
7   Sr Tom Hawkins      pears                2
8   Jose Hawkins        pears                2
9   Shanita             pineapple            0
10  Joe                 pineapple            0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with custom function - first create one big string of joined values, convert to lowercase and split, last use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with filtering all duplicated values:

```
from collections import Counter

def f(x):
    a = ' '.join(x).lower().split()
    return len([k for k, v in Counter(a).items() if v != 1])

df['count'] = df.groupby('fav_fruit')['Name'].transform(f)
print (df)
                  Name  fav_fruit  count
0               justin      apple      2
1        bieber justin      apple      2
2   Kris Justin bieber      apple      2
3              Kim Lee     orange      2
4              lee kim     orange      2
5          mary barnet     orange      2
6          tom hawkins      pears      2
7       Sr Tom Hawkins      pears      2
8         Jose Hawkins      pears      2
9              Shanita  pineapple      0
10                 Joe  pineapple      0
```

Comment: tried something similar using sets but it didnt work if word is not common in all the rows. I'm just evaluating your solution. will let you know if it works for entire dataset.